# IIS Redirect Permanent to part of old URL

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to redirect permanent this using IIS rewrite

**[www.domain.com/category/sub-category/product-slug](http://www.domain.com/category/sub-category/product-slug)** OR **[www.domain.com/category/product-slug](http://www.domain.com/category/product-slug)**

to

**[www.domain.com/product-slug](http://www.domain.com/product-slug)**

Old URLs are from magento2 while new site is on nopCommerce

Basically I want every URL to be redirected to domain.com/product-slug. How I can achieve this?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below rules:

```
<rule name="test1" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.test.com" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.test.com/{C:1}/{C:3}" />
</rule>
```

and

```
<rule name="test2" stopProcessing="true">  
    <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.test.com" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$" />
         </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.test.com/{C:1}/{C:2}" />
 </rule>
```

The body cannot contain "http://www. domain.com", so I use [www.test.com](http://www.test.com) instead.

Comment: category and product-slug are just placeholders. How can I do for every value of category. For example I want www.test.com/computers/desktops/awesome-desktop to www.test.com/awesome-desktop and so on. Thanks for help though.

Comment: @ghulam_ali I revised my answer, please check updated post.